# From CMD, is it possible to execute a command after a for loop using start to launch several parallel tasks, but only AFTER all tasks have completed?

Tags: for-loop, cmd, command-line, wait, multitasking

I'm running a command that modifies all the audio files in a folder, due to a bug in `ffmpeg`, I need to chain together an `ffmpeg` and `sox` command, but `sox` is really slow, so I run them in parallel, which dramatically speeds up the process (makes it about 10 times faster, probably the more cores in your CPU, the faster it will go). That all works fine.

The problem is that because those are all spawned as separate tasks, it returns and runs the commands after the FOR loop before it has completed the tasks. In my case, that's to delete the intermediate temp files (`del int_*.wav` in the example below). Here's a simplified example (removed most parameters to make it easier to read):

```
md "Ready" & (for %x in ("*.mp3") do (start "Convert" cmd /c "ffmpeg -i "%x" -f wav "int_%x.wav" & sox "int_%x.wav" -r 44100 "Ready\ready-%x"")) && del int_*.wav
```

That converts all the MP3 files in the current directory per my parameters to a different set of MP3 files in the destination directory (the `Ready` subdirectory). It uses .WAV files as intermediaries because those are lossless and fast.

The above runs correctly, except for the last part, `del int_*.wav`, because it tries to run that before all the START threads have finished, and so it does nothing.

It errors with:

```
Could Not Find C:\<parent directory name>\int_*.wav
```

Which is expected, because it gets to the DEL before it has created the files to delete. Hence my need to have it pause until the FOR loop has completed and all the START tasks have closed.

It does run the DEL command correctly if I leave out the `START` command and don't try to run them in parallel, but then it's very slow (this is how I originally did it, then came up with the above solution to make it faster):

```
md "Ready" & (for %x in ("*.mp3") do (ffmpeg -i "%x" -f wav "int_%x.wav" & start sox "int_%x.wav" -r 44100 "Ready\ready-%x")) & del int_*.wav
```

And note that this example only has the `DEL` command at the end, but in my actual use case, I have multiple commands after the loop, including a batch file, all chained together with `&` signs. So I can't use a solution that just provides a different way to delete the files. I need to have everything after the double closing parentheses wait to run until the loop has completed and all the started tasks have closed.

Also note that I'm intentionally running this as one command from the command prompt rather than via  a batch file. This is because I have to change a small varying subset of many parameters and generally run it on a subset of the files in a directory. So in this particular case, it's much easier to just paste the command and tweak the relevant parameters and filenames with wildcards than make a batch file and have to pass it everything every time. I'd like to keep it as a single CMD line if possible.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: As a work-around, I have taken to adding pause after the for loop and before the del command. That ensures it doesn't proceed until the user hits a key. Not too bad, but if someone can tell me a way to automatically wait to proceed until the start threads launched by the for loop have all finished, that would be significantly better (some of the post-loop tasks take a while, and it would be nice to have those done along with the contents of the loop when the user returns). A timeout might also work, but no way to know how long -- can vary a lot depending on the file sizes being converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid cmd these days. Everything is much easier in PowerShell, and many things that are impossible to do in cmd can be achievable in PowerShell

```
foreach (f in Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.mp3") {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        ffmpeg -i "$f" -f wav "int_$f.wav"
        sox "int_$f.wav" -r 44100 "Ready\ready-$f"
    }
}
Get-Job | Wait-Job
Remove-Item int_*.wav
```

Or you can pipe directly without `Get-Job` like this

```
foreach (f in ls "*.mp3") { sajb {
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -f wav "int_$f.wav"; sox "int_$f.wav" -r 44100 "Ready\ready-$f"
} } | wjb
del int_*.wav
```

Or even make it a one-liner

```
foreach (f in ls "*.mp3") { sajb { ffmpeg -i "$f" -f wav "int_$f.wav"; sox "int_$f.wav" -r 44100 "Ready\ready-$f" } } | wjb; rm int_*.wav
```

---

> So in this particular case, it's much easier to just paste the command and tweak the relevant parameters and filenames with wildcards than make a batch file and have to pass it everything every time

Nothing prevents you from setting a default value if the parameter is not set. This is possible in any shell scripting languages. Just pass the arguments that you need to change. However in batch you'll need to read arguments and set the flags manually while in PowerShell just define what you want with [`Param()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters) and everything will be handled automatically

---

Alternatively you can use [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)/[Wait-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process) instead of [Start-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)/[Wait-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job) but this is longer, less readable and may not work for some commands

```
Start-Process -PassThru {
    cmd /c "ffmpeg -i `"$f`" -f wav `"int_$f.wav`" & sox `"int_$f.wav`" -r 44100 `"Ready\ready-$f`""
} | Wait-Process
rm int_*.wav
```

Comment: I like the idea of migrating to PS, but I'm ignorant at PS work, so fall back to CMD. I tried your command, but get an error on the 'f' variable name. I think I may have figured out a way to get it working building on that. I'll post back here shortly.

Comment: I could get it to work IF I left out the sajb to run them in parallel. This part works without the error I got on yours, but I can't get it to run them all in parallel, like in my original example that works at CMD: md "Ready"; Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.mp3" | ForEach-Object { ffmpeg -i "$_" "int_$_.flac"; sox "int_$_.flac" -r 44100 "Ready\$_" }. But when I add the sajb and { } around the ffmpeg and sox commands, it just dumps a bunch of HasMoreData table blocks and does nothing.

Comment: Here's what each loop shows, but it doesn't actually create any files:
HasMoreData : True
StatusMessage :
Location : localhost
Command :  ffmpeg -i "$_" "int_$_.flac"; sox "int_$_.flac" -r 44100 "Ready\$_"
JobStateInfo : Running
Finished : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
InstanceId : f61ddb72-6f23-4b8e-a6ec-d76ee9d2c2b1
Id : 31
Name : Job31
ChildJobs : {Job32}
PSBeginTime : 6/29/2023 3:56:43 PM
PSEndTime :
PSJobTypeName : BackgroundJob
Output : {}
Error : {}
Progress : {}
Verbose : {}
Debug : {}
Warning : {}
Information : {}
State : Running. Any ideas?

Comment: I added another answer to this question that builds on phuclv's. Key is to be sure to upgrade to PowerShell 7 first. The easiest way to do this kind of parallel running of tasks from a loop is not possible in the default version of PowerShell (ver 5) included in Windows 11, but very simple in version 7.

Answer (score 0):

[untested]

```
for %%e in ('dir int_* 2^>nul^|find /c "int") do set starting=%%e
set /a converted=0
md "Ready" & (for %x in ("*.mp3") do (set /a converted+=1&ffmpeg -i "%x" -f wav "int_%x.wav" & start sox "int_%x.wav" -r 44100 "Ready\ready-%x"))
:wait
timeout /t 1 >nul
for %%e in ('dir int_* 2^>nul^|find /c "int") do set /a current=%%e-starting
if %current% neq %converted% goto wait
```

This shoud set `starting` to the number of `int_*` files originally in the directory, then count the conversions to be done in `converted`.

Then calculate the number completed in `current` and if not the same as the number in `converted`, wait another 1 second.

Comment: That's clever. I love the countdown concept. However, I believe that requires a batch file for the goto, yes? I'm trying to keep it to something I can run at a command line without using a file. Any way to do it as a single line?

Comment: Not that I can see. Quite apart from the loop, you'd need delayedexpansion to allow access to the variables' values, & that means at least two lines. I've no idea why you'd want to repeatedly retype the command - very error-prone. If you use a batch, placing the batch in one of the directories on the path will allow you to run it anywhere, and you could also supply parameters such as `int_`. Your `md` line needs to be adjusted for doubling the `%` in `%x` - I just copy/pasted your original.

Comment: To  @Magoo  maybe instead of a counter, there's a way to check if the file is there and delete each file as it's converted...? In any case, I've decided to ditch the good 'ole CMD approach for PS, which has an automated way of pausing until the running tasks have finished. Really quite elegant. See other responses on that.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell does seem to provide the best solution to this, because the wjb option dutifully waits for the running parallel tasks to all finish, then immediately runs the delete. Thanks to @phuclv for steering me down this path. However, this requires a few additional steps:

First, upgrade to PowerShell 7 (only 5.2 included by default with Windows 11, which has limits and problems with its parallel / StartJob functions. Either run from Microsoft Store (search for PowerShell) or, at a PS prompt, run: winget install --id Microsoft.Powershell --source winget

Then launch a new PowerShell 7 Terminal window. The old PowerShell version 5 will still be installed alongside version 7. To open the new one, launch a new Terminal window, then open a new tab, selecting "PowerShell" instead of "Windows PowerShell" (Windows Powershell is the old version 5).

Now you can run a command with the "ForEach-Object -parallel" like this:

md "Ready"; Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.mp3" | ForEach-Object -parallel { ffmpeg -i $*.name -f flac -af dynaudnorm -id3v2_version 3 ($*.name+".flac"); sox --norm=-3.25 ($*.fullname + ".flac") -c 2 -C 192 -r 44100 (".\Ready\ready-" + $*.name) } | wjb; rm *.flac

Additional considerations specific to PowerShell:

While you can use the StartJob function under version 5, that spawned tasks lose awareness of the current directory. In place of $*, you can use ($using:*), but I had trouble getting this to work (upgrading to version 7 and using -parallel was easier).

There is also a newer Start-ThreadJob which may be faster and more efficient than Start-Job, but at least for my purposes, the ForEach-Object -parallel" option worked perfectly.

Comment: Actually, turns out the way PS runs the tasks in parallel, it doesn't even need the Wait-Job (wjb) command. Leaving out "| wjb" yields the same result with one less step. It still pauses and waits until all the ffmpeg and sox commands have finished before deleting the intermediary files.